# Get html of view from controller - .NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, view, controller, preview

I want to make previews of one view on a homepage type view.  To do so, I'd like to call a ListPreviews Action.  I want this action to get the html body of a given view and then take the first hundred characters or so.

How can I access the actual html of a view from a controller?

Comment: Can you please let me know how I can help you further?

Answer (score 0):

This should be simple.
In your RouteConfig.cs set the defaults, mine looks like this:

```
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index2006", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

For your Controller/Model:

```
public class AView
{
    public string theHtml { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index2005(AView AView)
    {
        //put breakpoint here to see all the <html> here in view
        var result = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(AView.theHtml, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
        return Json(new
        {
            Greeting = "Returning data not used"
        }
        , @"application/json");
    }
```

For your view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="PassMe">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index2005</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".btn").click(function () {
                var AView = { theHtml: escape($("#PassMe").html()) };  //JSON.stringify($("#PassMe").html())
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/Index2005',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: AView,
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#detail").append(result.Greeting);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('Error');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button style="margin-bottom: 20px;" class="btn  btn-default">Click to pass HTML</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @bchattdeveloper  Can you please let me know how I can help you further?